# Study and research in computational number theory

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, research, computational-number-theory

I am an undergraduate student and i have completed courses like data structures and algorithms , discrete mathematics , elementary number theory (i have studied Burton's book completely), abstract algebra, topology.

I am mainly interested in computational (algorithmic) number theory because i have deep interest in algorithms and i didn't like abstract algebra course much but i enjoy computational number theory. Where should i head next now ?

I mean which are suggested books (note that i have read Burton's Number Theory) and what topic i can try to do research as an undergraduate.

Comment: See the references in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_number_theory#Further_reading

Comment: @lhf Thanks a lot . I will look into them

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Prime-Numbers-Computational-Richard-Crandall/dp/1441920501/

Comment: @AnginaSeng thanks a lot . can you suggest me about research thing ?

Comment: Consider browsing a journal such as [Mathematics of Computation](https://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journalsframework/mcom)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks a lot .

Comment: Also look at [Unsolved Problems in Number Theory](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387208602)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I will look into them . Thanks a lot

Comment: You say you did not like abstract algebra.  Keep in mind that a lot of number theory involves settings beyond the framework of $\mathbf Z$ and $\mathbf Q$, such as number fields and their ring of integers, and to extend concepts from $\mathbf Z$ or $\mathbf Q$ to these broader settings requires a lot of abstract algebra (and commutative algebra and more math than that).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following three books. The first one titled [**Computational Excursions in Analysis and Number Theory**](https://g.co/kgs/uAWULc) and authored by **Peter Borwein** is a collection of research problems and contains discussion and a comprehensive bibliography.

The second one is [**Computational Number Theory**](https://g.co/kgs/8FdTGn) authored by **Abhijit Das** for a comprehensive study on computational number theory.

The third book is an encyclopaedia for algorithms and computational aspects of algebraic number theory. The name of the book is [**A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory**](https://g.co/kgs/ULycTb) authored by **Henri Cohen**.

Hope these will be of some help.